# Не могу авторизоваться на сайте

Tags: java, jsoup

Пытаюсь зайти на сайт с помощью JSOUP через эту [страницу](https://forum.grodno.net/index.php?action=login).

Не получается авторизоваться. Вот мой код:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
            .connect("https://forum.grodno.net/")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://forum.grodno.net/index.php?action=login")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0")
            .data("frmLogin[user]", "тут логин", "frmLogin[passwrd]", "тут пароль")
            .cookies(res.cookies())
            .post();
```

Вот скрин кода формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пройти авторизацию.

Comment: Там ведь нужно отправлять + к этому всему хеш пароля

Comment: @GenCloud Вы знаете как это сделать? Я пытаюсь его передать через .data("hash_passwrd", "тут хеш") - все также не получается авторизоваться. Может, я просто не правильно обращаюсь к формам ввода логина и пароля (frmLogin[user] и frmLogin[passwrd])?

Comment: Отловите данные формы при авторизации браузером, покажет хеш, посмотрите кодировщик и пробуйте сделать аналогичный

Comment: Вам необходимо реализовать код, который отвечает за подстановку хэша.Вот эта в-ция в js [ссылка](http://pastebin.com/Q4V2369j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получился такой класс:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Main {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0";
    // credentials
    private static final String USER_NAME = "";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                .connect("https://forum.grodno.net/index.php?action=login")
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();
        final String sessionAttr = res.parse()
                .body()
                .getElementById("frmLogin")
                .attr("onsubmit")
                .replaceAll("hashLoginPassword\\(this, '", "")
                .replaceAll("'\\);", "");
        final Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup
                .connect("https://forum.grodno.net/index.php?action=login2")
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .cookies(res.cookies())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Referer", "https://forum.grodno.net/index.php?action=login2")
                .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                .data("user", USER_NAME)
                .data("passwrd", PASSWORD.replaceAll(".", "*"))
                .data("cookielength", "9000")
                .data("hash_passwrd", hashLoginPassword(USER_NAME, PASSWORD, sessionAttr))
                .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        System.out.println(res2.cookies());
        System.out.println(res2.statusCode());
    }

    private static String hashLoginPassword(String user, String password, String sessionAttr) {
        return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(user.toLowerCase() + password) + sessionAttr);
    }
}
```

Требуемые зависимости:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Благодарю тебя, добрый человек!)